# Dynamic legend for Kendo UI for Angular 2 charts

Tags: kendo-ui-angular2

Does anybody know how to generate dynamic legends based an array?
I can't find it in the examples / manual.

Any help would be really appreciated,

Please see my code below:

```
<kendo-chart >
        <kendo-chart-title text="Gender"></kendo-chart-title>
        <kendo-chart-legend position="top" labels="SearchStatistics.GenderStatistics[?].Index">
          </kendo-chart-legend>
        <kendo-chart-series>
            <kendo-chart-series-item type="pie" [data]="SearchStatistics.GenderStatistics">
            </kendo-chart-series-item>
        </kendo-chart-series>
    </kendo-chart>
```

Where GenderStatistics is an array that holds 2 properties, Index and Value.

Example:

```
0:
{Index: "M", Value: 3}
1:
{Index: "U", Value: 1}
2:
{Index: "F", Value: 2}
```

So the idea here would be to get 3 Legends, M, F and U.

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The series `field` and `categoryField` properties should be set, in order to render the pie chart. The `field` property provides the value that will be shown in the pie chart. The `categoryField` provides the label.

```
<kendo-chart-series-item type="pie"
    [data]="SearchStatistics.GenderStatistics"
    field="Value" categoryField="Index">
</kendo-chart-series-item>
```

See [this plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/C2i1jiKEghGx8J6JRKwv?p=preview).

Comment: Hi Alex, Thanks for your answer.......works like a charm. Would it be able to show the actual values in the chart as well?

Comment: You can achieve this either via the [series labels](http://plnkr.co/edit/C2i1jiKEghGx8J6JRKwv?p=preview) or via [tooltips](http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/charts/chart/tooltips/)